# Chat & make scroll bar set in bottom and appending new messages.

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chat

Hello all I am working on a **social networking website** where I have a **chat box**.
everything is working fine in the  chatbox except that I have to reload the div after every 5 seconds to get the new messages which is causing some problems for me like the same database query is going to run over again and again after every 5 seconds. and also the scroller goeson  top every time the chatbox reloads i can not set it as to scroll to bottom after every 5 seconds because there may be someone just reading the messages and he will not want to scroll the box back again and again.
so in short what i want to ask  that is there any other way for geting the new messages in chat box .
and if this is the only way can you please tell me how to code for this logic
if the scroller is  above 10px fromthe bottom of div scroll to bottom and append new messages other wise just append new messages.

Here is my code:

```
 var autoload1 = setInterval(
    function showthemess1()
    {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'chitchatback2.php', 
        data: {'chattingwith':"<?=$nameIS2['id']?>"},
        success: function(chats){
        $("#chatboxdiv").empty().append(chats);
        } });
    }, 5000);
```

for making the scroller come to bottom i can do like

```
   $(".bechmsgbox").animate({
scrollTop: $("#chatboxdiv")[0].scrollHeight
},'slow');
```

Comment: Consider only loading the new messages asynchronous. So every 5 secs send a request to the server with a timestamp as parameter, when the last request has been made. The server responds with only the new messages, if there are any. These new messages get appended to the chat box content. When receiving the response from the server, save the current time for the next request.
Quick fiddle without request and manual loading by clicking a button: http://jsfiddle.net/sQ6ZP/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) for this kind of situations.
try [this](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) example as well

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you explore services such as pusher so that you dont have to keep pulling.  http://pusher.com/

Answer (score 0):

you should store latest requested post ID in variable, request only new post and append those.